# Need to change the color of line according to score on y-axis, I am using react-chartjs-2 for linear graph

Tags: reactjs, graph, frontend, chart.js

I tried returning an array in the "borderColor" Property but it only picks the color on the first index, I need to change the color of line according to score on y-axis, chart.js -v 4.0.1 and the version of react-chartjs-2 is 5.0.1

```
const LinearGraph = ({ graphData }) => {
  // Extract times and scores from graphData
  const times = graphData.map((dataPoint) => dataPoint.time);
  const scores = graphData.map((dataPoint) => dataPoint.score);

  // Determine the line and dot color based on the score
  const getLineColor = (score) => {
    if (score >= 80) {
      return "green"; // Green for scores >= 80
    } else if (score >= 50) {
      return "yellow"; // Yellow for scores >= 50
    } else {
      return "red"; // Red for scores < 50
    }
  };


  const data = {
    labels: times,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "",
        data: scores,
        borderColor: scores.map((score) => getLineColor(score)),
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)", // Set the background color for the area under the graph
        fill: "origin", // Fill the area under the graph
        pointRadius: 3,
        pointHoverRadius: 6,
        pointBackgroundColor: scores.map((score) => getLineColor(score)),
        pointBorderColor: scores.map((score) => getLineColor(score)), // Set dot color based on score
        // lineTension: 0.4,
      },
    ],
  };
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.